# Replace into (mysql) equivalent in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I want to do a batch insert in mongodb , but if the record exists already it should replace it with the new one.There is update command but its not possible to do it in batch.Any idea whether it is possible? I am using java api.
Thanks

Edit:
As my collection size is not very huge, i am renaming the collection with drop Target option set to true and creating a new collection with this data.As i cant risk deleting and creating a new collection this is better, but it will be awesome if there is replace into equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having any primary key in your collection, then it will replace automatically.Make sure your documents have _id key.

Comment: I tried doing that, but its ignoring (similar to insert ignore into..), are you sure or am i making a mistake?

Comment: Can you  post a sample of your document structure?.

Comment: { "_id" : 1 , "doc_created" : "20110722165208693" , "screenName" : "k4rtk"} , then inserting  { "_id" : 1 , "doc_created" : "20110722165208693" , "screenName" : "k4rtk123"} but its not getting replaced, still shows the old one

Answer (score 0):

Look at mongodb document:

```
Shorthand for insert/update is save - if _id value set, the record is updated if it exists or inserted if it does not; if the _id value is not set, then the record is inserted as a new one.
```

in http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html